# Libgdx: Dialog doesn't listen the input

Tags: input, dialog, libgdx

My goal is to show a Dialog to the user in order to make him able to choose which Actor to add to the Stage. I do this in the main Screen of the application that implements Screen and GestureListener. (I need GestureListener to listen double click). I create the Dialog in the overrided touchDown() method.
When the dialog appears, it does not work. The screen keeps listening the input in the **touchDown** if i click on any point of the screen.

This is the code:

```
public class SquareDefense implements Screen, GestureListener {
    ....
    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {

        System.out.println("touchDown");

        if(squareDefenseTable.getActor(x, y) != null) {
            // rotate the clicked actor!
            squareDefenseTable.rotateActor(x, y);
        }
        else {
            showDialog();
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog("Choose an action", skin) {

            @Override
            protected void result(Object object) {
                boolean exit = (Boolean) object;
                if (exit) {
                    Gdx.app.exit();
                } else {
                    remove();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public Dialog show(Stage stage) {
                return super.show(stage);
            }

            @Override
            public void cancel() {
                super.cancel();
            }

            @Override
            public float getPrefHeight() {
                return 50f;
            }
        };
        dialog.button("Yes", true);
        dialog.button("No", false);
        dialog.key(Input.Keys.ENTER, true);
        dialog.key(Input.Keys.ESCAPE, false);
        dialog.show(stage);
    }
}
```

Comment: i wonder if your problem was solved, if yes could you please set your question as resolved by choosing correct answer, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to add this line of code :

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

tell me if that works

Comment: In the show() method i have Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new GestureDetector(this));

Comment: With this line you remove the stage as input processor. To add both, you need an input multiplexer.

Comment: Thank you. Now it works, even if when i choose an action on the Dialog and i add an Actor to the Stage, the background of the stage disappear

Comment: Great that it's works now :) , please put the detail of your solution so others can benefit from it, and don't forget to rate answer, good luck